Clarify lucida fonts license
Support TUG by buying a nice font that includes many weights for math? I'm all in!
Before ordering I check the license and find this:

1b) End User may use the Lucida Fonts on at most five (5) workstations and two (2) printers, for his or her personal use only.  Additional usage requires additional licenses.

My brain kind of refuses to believe that this means what it says. Am I seriously supposed to pay another $190 every time I happen to use a different printer twice? Like when I use the printer in the cafeteria instead of one of the two printers down the hall, bam pay $190!
Can someone confirm that I didn't misread the license?
Also if it's really that, I'd love to know more about the story here... How did TUG end up offering a font with a license like this?

I’m no lawyer, but I’ve always understood that to mean “at most 5 workstations and 2 printers” simultaneously, as in a secretarial pool. If your laptop breaks and you have to buy a new one, that shouldn’t mean you need a new license. At least I hope it doesn’t mean that!

Possibly it is some time since anybody actually read the licence .... This seems to predate the development of personal computers ('workstation') and to come from a time when, in order to print using a font, you installed the font into the printer.

you should ask TUG if you feel unsure about the license. Whatever we are telling you here is not binding. But imho you are not using the font in a printer if you simply print a document but only if you download the full font permanantly into the printer memory.

As Ulrike says I believe this refers to installing the font on the printer, the paragraph above already licences you to print documents using the font. But legal questions are off topic here

Ah it makes sense that this part is about installing fonts on printers, thanks!

Yes, two printers is about installing the font on the printer (rare in our TeXworld), not merely printing documents.
Chuck and I put an official statement about this on https://tug.org/store/lucida/licensing.html. I quote:

The end-user license limits use to five workstations and two printers. The intent here is to limit installation of the fonts on that many devices, but does not limit use of the fonts for creating and printing documents that embed the fonts—within the embedding terms and conditions of the license—on as many computers and printers as you like.

(From time to time, we have tried to come up with a change to the actual license wording that would be clearer, but have not yet succeeded in that.)

Thanks for the clarification! There's still one point that's not clear to me: how can I be allowed to use the font for creating documents on as many computers as I like, when I'm only allowed to install it on five? (Or does "five workstations" only apply to simultaneous use on multiple computers as Thérèse suggests?)


Five workstations and two printers applies to where the font is installed.  By the license, it's not ok to install the font on, say, 10 computers just because you're only using 5 simultaneously (somehow :).



You could use the font on more computers than where it is installed via, e.g., installing it in a TeX tree and then using that tree after ssh-ing to the installation machine, or mounting it via NFS, etc. That's ok, as long as it's for your personal use.



Chuck writes, informally: ... the reasonable intention is that a single user should not copy and distribute the fonts so that many other users will have routine access to the fonts at the composition end of document creation and development ...



The license is not tied to individual machines, e.g., in Therese's case, if laptop X with Lucida gets broken and replaced by laptop Y, it's perfectly fine to reinstall the fonts on Y.


Thanks for the precisions! It's quite clear to me now.
